# Facebook SDK & custom button Login in react-native 0.60+ not working

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0

i'm trying to implement Facebook login in my React-Native app but for some reason, it's throwing `Cannot read property 'logInWithPermissions' of undefined`.
I'm using `React-Native 0.60.4`.
I've downloaded `FacebookSDK 5.3.0` (_Stable framework)

Attempted using Cocoapod but after some research, many people don't suggest using it because it messes up the project.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Downloaded FacebookSDK 5.3.0 (current latest up to 08/15/19)
2. Dropped the `FBSDKCoreKit.framework`, `FBSDKLoginKit.framework` and `FBSDKShareKit.framework` inside a folder as `~/Documents/FacebookSDK`.
3. Also dropped those 3 framework files inside my project in XCode in the `/Frameworks` folder.
4. Just in case, I also added the path `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` in the Framework Search Paths under Build Settings.
5. Made a Build on XCode, it's successful.
6. I download react-native-fbsdk from my react-native project. It downloads version 1.0.1.
7. I don't add `libRTCFBSDK.a` file in the `Link binary with Libraries` because it throws an error saying the `FBSDKShareKit.h isn't found`.

This is what I do on my AuthView.js, I add this to a simple bound onPress event in a TouchableOpacity.

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginManager,
} = FBSDK;

handleFacebookLogin() {
        LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'publish_actions']).then(
            (result) => {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    console.log('Login cancelled')
                } else {
                    console.log('Login success with permissions: ' + result.grantedPermissions.toString())
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Login fail with error: ' + error)
            }
        )
    }
```

Now, I notice that inside Facebook's `FBLoginManager.js` this is the function being called

```
logInWithPermissions(permissions: Array<string>): Promise<LoginResult> {
    return LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(permissions);
  },
```

Whenever I hover LoginManager, it says it's **undefined**. Why would this be undefined? When it's literally a const on top of the file

`const LoginManager = require('react-native').NativeModules.FBLoginManager;`

Can anyone help me? I've been struggling for 4 days now. I already attempted installing it with cocoapods, no success. Then doing `react-native link react-native-fbsdk` no success... a lot of people suggested NOT using link but doing it manually.

What else could I try? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add libRTCFBSDK.a file in the Link binary with Libraries . To fix the 'FBSDKShareKit.h isn't found' issue change ~/Documents/FacebookSDK to $(HOME)/Documents/FacebookSDK

Comment: Hi Mehran, thanks for replying. I did this now, and as my trial before, it throws a different error. 
`
/Users/marian-mac/Documents/dev/MyApp/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/login/RCTFBSDKLoginButtonManager.m:22:9: 'React/RCTComponentEvent.h' file not found`

Comment: After searching many hours in Google, some people suggested doing #import "RCTComponentEvent.h" but that didn't work either. I don't know what else to try. Any idea?

Comment: OMG yes!!! i did what this guy mentioned about the RCTComponentEvent.h plus your suggestion and it worked! i can't believe it! Justi n case anyone else is in struggle, it's this comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/580#issuecomment-512356091